# How to create and package a custom component for Mule Studio?

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule and hoping to avoid going in the completely wrong direction.  I would like to create a component, which other devs can add to their Components lists in Mule Studio (to be dropped into their flows).

I see that I can create a Java class that implements callable, which can be added to a Flow by using a Java component and setting its "Class Name" to the one I created.  Is there a good way that I can use this to package as a component that can be plugged in to Mule Studio?  Or is Mule Devkit the best option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule DevKit is the very best option for this. Other alternatives imply messing with Eclipse-related code. You don't want that, go DevKit: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+DevKit